# Filtering out a number at the start of a string which has a certain pattern

Tags: php, string, filter, numbers

I'm trying to filter a number out of a string if that string starts with @.
Here's what I thought would do the trick, but it returns nothing more than a blank page.

(May contain lots of mistakes as I'm new to PHP.)

```
<?php
$String = "@1234 Hello this is a message.";
$StringLength = 1;
Echo "Filtering the number after the @ out of " .$String;
If (substr($String , 0, 1)="@"){ //If string starts with @
    While (is_int(substr($String,1,$StringLength))){ //Check if the X length string after @ is a number.
            $StringLength=$StringLength+1; //If it was a number, up StringLength by one.
    }
    If ($StringLength >= 2){ //If the number is only 1 character long StringLength will be 2, loop completed once.
        $Number = substr($String,1,$StringLength-1);
        Echo $Number;
    }
    Else{ //The string started with @ but the While has never run because it was false.
        Echo "The @ isn't followed by a number.";
    }
Else{ //If string doesn't start with @
    Echo "String doesn't start with @.";
}
?>
```

What's wrong with my script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(substr($String , 0, 1)=="@")
//                       ^^ 2 equal signs for equality comparison.
```

---

BTW your function can be written simply with regex ([example](http://www.ideone.com/Krs0K)). And to get the initial character, use `$string[0]`.

```
if (preg_match('/^@(\\d+)/', $string, $results)) {
   echo $results[1];
} else {
   if ($string[0] != '@')
     echo "String doesn't start with @.";
   else
     echo "The @ isn't followed by a number.";
}
```